# JDialog does not show components

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, contentpane

I'm having a strange problem with a class that extends JDialog:

```
class MyDialog extends JDialog {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 11564288421L;

    public MyDialog(JFrame owner, MyObject object) {
        super(owner, true);
        setSize(300, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(owner);
        String title = "Object ID: " + object.getId(); 
        setTitle(title);
        setVisible(true);

        JLabel lblTitle = new JLabel(title);
        lblTitle.setBounds(0, 0, this.getWidth(), 22);
        lblTitle.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18));
        lblTitle.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        getContentPane().add(lblTitle);
    }
}
```

When I call it with `new MyDialog(existingJFrameInstance, existingMyObjectInstance);`, `MyDialog` is displayed and well-titled, but there's nothing in its `ContentPane`.

If I change the class into:

```
class MyDialog extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 11564288421L;

    public MyDialog(JFrame owner, MyObject object) {
        super();
        setSize(300, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(owner);
        String title = "Object ID: " + object.getId(); 
        setTitle(title);
        setVisible(true);

        JLabel lblTitle = new JLabel(title);
        lblTitle.setBounds(0, 0, this.getWidth(), 22);
        lblTitle.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18));
        lblTitle.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        getContentPane().add(lblTitle);
    }
}
```

Everything works just fine. I can't imagine what's happening here :\

I need the Window to be Modal, that's why I must go with `JDialog` instead of `JFrame`.

I tried using `this.pack();`, `this.validate();`, `getContentPane().revalidate();`, `getContentPane().repaint();` etc etc etc in every possible combination and I am in the EDT (`SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()` returns `true`).

Please help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just move your `setVisible(true);` call to the end of your constructor.

Comment: @tmh `setVisible(true);` must be last codes line in constructor, otherwise you showed `empty container`

Comment: Indeed, `setVisible(true)` should be last code line in the constructor, otherwise you'll note a delay in the controls display, but in this case, the problem is the `getContentPane()` invocation for the `JDialog` (confirmed by test)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `getContentPane()` invocations in the `JDialog` version, it should work